# How to copy files to root folder

Tags: android, filesystems, copy

normally it copies files to /data/ata/app directory. I want to have it int / of internal. How do I do this? Do I need special permissions?
                                                 ff

Answer (score 0):

Your device needs to be rooted and your application needs root access.

Comment: Add to it: reason being "security" otherwise any app could overwrite/read any other apps data.

Comment: ok and some other folder which is accessible when I connect normally via usb? anything but /data..

Comment: Sounds to me like a very different question. Just add the file to external storage. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal